# Showing notifications in Google Chrome only when host name changes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to send notifications on URL changes, but only if the host name changes. For instance, moving from `http://example.com` to `http://example.org` should trigger a notification, but not moving from `http://example.com` to `http://example.com/#foo`

My current code:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if(changeInfo.status=='complete'){
    $.ajax({
      url:"http://example.com",
      data: {
        url: tab.url
      },
      success: function(res){
        var opt = {};
        if(res['status'] === 'safe'){
          opt = {
            type: "basic",
            iconUrl: "images/safe-noti.jpg",
            title: "It's safe site",
            message: "success Message"
          };
        }
        else if( res['status'] === 'unsafe'){
          opt = {
            type: "basic",
            iconUrl: "images/unsafe-noti.jpg",
            title: "not safe site",
            message: "error message"
          };
        }
        chrome.notifications.create('', opt);
      },
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: @MattCooper Thanks for editing.. i tried the above code

Comment: Your code appears to be significantly more complex than the description you have provided.  Your code appears to perform an AJAX call to some URL (presumably `example.com` is just an example) to check if the URL is safe. If your question is *really* about only doing something (showing a notification) when the host name changes, then the AJAX call should be removed from the code you are showing and just use something like `showNotification()` or generically, `performNewUrlTasks(tabId)`.  Doing so is part of making a *minimal*, but *complete*, [mcve].

Comment: Is your question is about to how to create the notification of is it about changing the host? It's not clear here.

Comment: @PawełPsztyć 
It's ok to send notifications. my question is about changing the host.
I dont want to send duplicate notifications on a page.